python nested dict multikey method suggestion
apparently, there is no built-in dict method (let's call it .nestkey) for dynamic key addressing in multi-nested dict structures. this can be demanding when dealing with complex dict structures,
e.g., dic_1.nestkey(list_of_keys_A) = value
instead of manually doing dic_1["key_1"]["subkey_2"]["subsubkey_3"].. = value.
this is not to be confused with level-1 assignment: dic_1["key_1"] = value_1, dic_2["key_2"] = value_2, ...
i know it's generally good practice to avoid nested structures, but when necessary, dynamic addressing is powerful:
list_values = [1, 2, 3]; ii = -1
for list_nestedkeys_i in [list_nestedkeys_A, list_nestedkeys_B, list_nestedkeys_C]:
    ii += 1; dic.nestkey(list_nestedkeys_i) = list_values[ii]
# endfor

for this purpose, i suggest implementing .nestkey as a built-in dict method. here’s how it could be expressed in method format:
def nestkey(self, keys, value):
    d = self  # the nested dict
    for key in keys[:-1]:  # traverse to the second last key
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = {}  # create a nested dict if key doesn't exist
        # endif
        d = d[key]  # move deeper into the dict
    # endfor
    d[keys[-1]] = value  # set the value for the final key
# enddef


Unless I'm mistaken, this is a suggestion for a change to the Python language, rather than a question about it. I would suggest adding it to the issue tracker for python as a feature request here

thx NEPTTUNE for the provided link, it has been useful for proposing a PEP in python.org. Because i had the inquiry of how to solve the problem i leave here the self-response to the problem, with the functions fun_setnest and fun_getnest respectively. best. j.

if anyone interested in the corresponding PEP proposal, here is the ref, https://discuss.python.org/t/dict-built-in-get-set-methods-for-nested-keys/64615

since there is no dict built-in method for that, here is the solution in function format (instead of method format). it has been extended to set/get respective functions, namely fun_setnest and fun_getnest,
def fun_setnest(dic, lis_nestkey, value): 
    d = dic
    for key in lis_nestkey[:-1]:  # traverse to the second last key
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = {}  # create a nested dict if key doesn't exist
        #endif

        d = d[key]  # move deeper into the dict
    #endfor

    d[lis_nestkey[-1]] = value  # set the value for the final key

    return dic
    
#enddef fun_setnest


def fun_getnest(dic, lis_nestkey): 
    d = dic
    for key in lis_nestkey[:-1]:  # traverse to the second last key
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = {}  # create a nested dict if key doesn't exist
        #endif

        d = d[key]  # move deeper into the dict
    #endfor

    return d[lis_nestkey[-1]]  # get the value for the final key
#enddef fun_getnest

